# Speed travelling wave solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am currently reading chapter 9.2. Traveling Fronts in J. Keener's Mathematical physiology and I don't understand the following:

> Consider the bistable equation $$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial x^2}+f(V) \tag{1}$$
> where $f(V)$ has three zeros at $0, a,$ and $1$, where $0 <a< 1$. The values $V =0$ and
> $V= 1$ are stable steady solutions of the ODE $\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} =f(V)$.
> We seek a solution of the form
> $V(x, t) =U(x + ct)=U(\xi)$.
> By substituting this into (1) we obtain $$U_{\xi \xi} − cU_{\xi} + f(U) =0 \tag{2}.$$For $U(\xi)$ it must be that $f(U(\xi)) \to0$ as $\xi\to \pm\infty$. To study (2) we write
> $$U_{\xi} =W, W_{\xi} =cW − f(U) \tag{3}.$$

Now what I don't understand:

> First of all, we can determine the sign of c. If a monotone increasing $(U_{\xi} > 0)$
> connecting trajectory exists, we can multiply (2) by $U_{\xi}$ and integrate from $\xi=-\infty$ to $\xi=\infty$ with the result that $$c\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}W^2d\xi=\int^1_0f(u)du \tag{4}$$

How exactly do I obtain (4)? I see $c\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}W^2d\xi$ is from the second term in (3) with $W^2=U_{\xi}U_{\xi}$ but why is the $U_{\xi \xi}$ from (3) gone and how do you get $\int^1_0f(u)du$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$U''(z)-c~U'(z)+f(U(z))=0\\ U''(z)U'(z)-c~{U'(z)}^2+f(U(z))U'(z)=0 \\ c~U'(z)^2=U''(z)U'(z)+f(U(z))U'(z)$$

Note that
$$U''U'=\frac{1}{2}\mathrm D(U'U')$$

So
$$c\int_{-\infty}^\infty {U'(z)}^2\mathrm dz=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{2}\mathrm D(U'U')(z)\mathrm dz+\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(U(z))U'(z)\mathrm dz $$

In regard to the second term in the equation, it is
$$\frac{1}{2}\lim_{z\to\infty}{U'(z)}^2-\frac{1}{2}\lim_{z\to-\infty}{U'(z)}^2$$
In order for the integral on the LHS to possibly converge, **both of these limits must be zero**. So
$$c\int_{-\infty}^\infty {U'(z)}^2\mathrm dz=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(U(z))U'(z)\mathrm dz$$
**IF** $U$ is invertible, which is to say it is monotone (say, monotone increasing) with finite limits $\lim_{z\to-\infty}U(z)=a$, $\lim_{z\to\infty}U(z)=b$ then we can introduce the $u$ substitution
$$U(z)=u~~,~~\mathrm du=U'(z)\mathrm dz \\ \implies \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(U(z))U'(z)\mathrm dz=\int_a^b f(u)\mathrm du$$

The author has made the *assumption* that $a=0~,~b=1$, and he really should have said so. So assuming this is the case you of course get
$$c\int_{-\infty}^\infty {U'(z)}^2\mathrm dz=\int_0^1f(u)\mathrm du$$

Comment: Is the same true if we seek a solution of the form $V(x, t) =U(x - ct)=U(\xi)$ instead of $U(x + ct)=U(\xi)$ now?

Comment: @Uhmm I think so?? You just need to check that $(2)$ takes the same form with the substitution $c\to -c$.